# Close button in Full Screen html5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-video

I have an online gaming site, and when the person clicks the "go fullscren" button, the game is in full screen.

My code is:

```
 Game:
 <iframe  id="videoElement"  seamless="seamless" id="iframegame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="433" width="770.4132075471698" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" allowfullscreen="true" webkit-playsinline="true" src="//html5.GameDistribution.com/ed10c5476d9c405191a6269d648f895e/?gp=1?gp=1&amp;siteid=158&amp;channelid=1&amp;siteLocale=tr-TR&amp;spilStorageId=94208775588" style="width: 741px; height: 416.692px;"></iframe>

 Button Full Screen:   
<button id="goFS">Go Fullscreen</button>
    <script>
      var goFS = document.getElementById("goFS");
      goFS.addEventListener("click", function() {
          var videoElement = document.getElementById("videoElement");
          videoElement.requestFullscreen();
      }, false);
    </script>
```

Something like that:

When the person clicks, the game is in full screen:[image]

However, how do I add a "close button" so that the game returns to its normal size when in full screen?

something like this (notice the red button in the upper right corner of the screen):[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [document.exitFullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/exitFullscreen) to exit the fullscreen mode:

Add click event on your close button:

```
closeButton.onclick = function (event) { 
    document.exitFullscreen() 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the button only when the page is in fullscreen, use the code bellow:

```
if(window.fullScreen){
// show button
}
```

Check the js exitFullscreen() method to close fullscreen:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_exitfullscreen.asp